# create generic mvc view in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I have raised similar question before, have got no answers.

How can I create a generic mvc4 view that can display list of or a single model that is passed to it. model can be either Person or Organization or Party whatever that is passed to it.

Comment: The 1st thing that comes to my mind is to have a common base class for Person, Organization etc and have the view use that model (of base class).

Comment: The reason why you got no answers if you ask me is because what you're trying to do makes no sense. How is your view going to handle the variety of different object types that you're passing in? Unless you're willing to write a massive case statement in your view I don't see why you would want to have a view which can handle multiple object types. Perhaps if you can provide more context to your question we would be able to provide a better answer...

Comment: There are some tables in database that share similar column, means like same number of data and its types are also same. In that case we want to use a generic view to display the data and have edits on that.. I am not how can we develop that!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking for something like:

```
@model MyViewModel<T> where T : IViewModel
```

... then that is not supported by Razor.

You may be able to use something like this:

```
@model MyViewModel<IViewModel>
```

... that way you could define all types that could be passed as follows

```
public class Person : IViewModel { ... }
public class Organisation : IViewModel { ... }
public class Party : IViewModel { ... }
```

Comment: Is this answer still valid?

Answer (score 4):

Please, DON'T DO THAT!!

You should make a view for each kind of object / list of objects.

However, yu can still reuse elements:

- keep the common part (menu, header, footer...) on the site layout
- make a view for each kind of object
- make a view for each kind of list. in this vie you can use the object's view as a partial view and render it as many times as object are on the list.

Another possibility is to make templates for "Display For" for each kind of object. You can define a view for each kind of object, and store it in an special folder. When you use `Html.Display` or `Html.DisplayFor`in your templates, the system will choose and render the right template depending on the type of the object to display. (You could also make named templates, and select them by name). For an introduction on this technique, [look at this excellent posts by Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).

But I insist, please, don't make a "generic view", as this will add extra complexity (check if it's a list or a simple object, get the type of the object, choose how to display it and display it). You can make very simple views by reusing the elements as explained, and letting the controllers decide which view to show for each object or list of object. Or use templates. In this way your system will be easier to maintain and less prone to errors because of added complexity (you don't need to change the same template all the time, but to add new templates, with very few code on them)

What I can't understand is why you want to have a simple view. What's the reason for it?

Comment: Yup I agree with this answer. The level of complexity you will introduce will far out outweigh any benefits that you gain.

Comment: @JotaBe - thanks for your explanation, Are you asking why do I need a generic view? because I am confused i have never mentioned simple view.

Comment: @mmssaann Excuse me, I meant a "single" view, or "just one view for everything". And yes, i want to know why, becasue in this way perhaps I can give better advice.

Comment: I am also not exactly sure why the management has taken this decision. Let me get some clarity and I will surely let you know.

Answer (score 1):

```
@model MyViewModel<IViewModel>
```

If you define a model like this then this error occurs:

> Server Error in '/' Application.

---

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `MyViewModel\'1[Person]`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `MyViewModel'1[IViewModel]`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a Generic View Use below code. dynamic is an inbuilt keyword that accepts any model.It worked fine for me

`@model dynamic`
or
`@model IEnumerable<dynamic>`

Comment: How to bind to Input elements? i.e. `Html.TextBoxFor`