# Is there anything else I can do to DRY up these views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dry

I am copy / pasting so much, I feel there must be something I can do to improve this code.

Or have I taken DRY razor views as far as they can go?

For example my EditPet.cshtml view looks like this:

```
@model PetEditViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Partial("_ValidationSummary", ViewData.ModelState)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Item.ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Item)
    @Html.Partial("_SaveOrCancelButtons")
}
```

And my EditShoe.cshtml view looks like this:

```
@model ShoeEditViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Partial("_ValidationSummary", ViewData.ModelState)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Item.ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Item)
    @Html.Partial("_SaveOrCancelButtons")
}
```

And so on... for about 30 different models.  Ditto for Create and Delete views. The only line that varies is the model declaration at the top.

**What I've Tried / Considered**

1. Using `Html.Partial()` has helped me avoid quite a bit of duplication.  But it seems unreasonable to take that route any further.
2. I have looked into generic razor views, but this has been [recommended against](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17568766/1778169), and any solutions I've seen appear overly complicated to me.

   - [Using a generic model in ASP.NET MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735903/using-a-generic-model-in-asp-net-mvc-razor)
   - [How can I create a generic view model in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423977/how-can-i-create-a-generic-view-model-in-mvc)
3. A third possibility I've considered is to use templating and generate these views automatically.  But I'd rather not take that approach because they'll still need maintaining (or recreating each time).
4. Finally I've considered shifting the duplicated code into an editortemplate.  But I can't see any benefit in shifting the duplication from one location to another.

Comment: Are you saying that the only controls your generating are associated with the `Item` property in your model?

Comment: Yes. ` model.Item` holds the data model to be edited. Some VM have other properties (e.g. drop down options) but most don't.  But even editng data models directly, I get the same repitition.

Comment: So I assume `Item` might be one `type` (e.g. `Pet.cs`) in one view and another `type` (`Shoe.cs`)` in the other view. If so, then I think you have gone as far as you can/should. While you could, for example create a `HtmlHelper` extension method that generates all the html using just one line of code (say) `@Html.MyFormFor(m => m)`, there needs to be a point where readability comes first.

Comment: Yep, correct. Thanks (again) Stephen. If you can shift that into an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: My comments are really just an opinion and not appropriate as an answer :)

Comment: I beg to differ it really helped me out. Thanks.